# css color overlay on every image hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to overlay each image to the red background color with css, but so far I have not been successful and all enclosed image overlay.

Any thoughts?

```css
.gallery-overlay {
    background: rgba(200,30,30,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.gallery-images:hover .gallery-overlay {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-recent-gallery">
 <div class="gallery-images">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <div class="gallery-overlay"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="gallery-images">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <div class="gallery-overlay"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="gallery-images">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <div class="gallery-overlay"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check it now

```css
.gallery-overlay {
    background: rgba(200,30,30,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.gallery-images:hover .gallery-overlay {
    display: block;
}
.gallery-images{position:relative; overflow:hidden; display:inline-block}
```

```html
<div class="box-recent-gallery">
 <div class="gallery-images">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <div class="gallery-overlay"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="gallery-images">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <div class="gallery-overlay"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="gallery-images">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <div class="gallery-overlay"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make this answer checked if this helps you and up vote it :)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.gallery-overlay {
    background: rgba(200,30,30,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.gallery-images {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}
.gallery-images:hover .gallery-overlay {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-recent-gallery">
 <div class="gallery-images">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <div class="gallery-overlay"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="gallery-images">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <div class="gallery-overlay"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="gallery-images">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <div class="gallery-overlay"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```